# subtracting a number from pandas series except specific element

Tags: pandas, series

I have a pandas series like this.

```
cluster_grtr_6
Out[100]: 
Clusters
Cluster 1    7
Cluster 4    7
Cluster 5    8
Name: quant_bought, dtype: int64
```

And after applying some condition I get a variable `a`.

```
a
Out[101]: 
3    Cluster 5
Name: Clusters, dtype: object
```

I want to subtract 6 from every element of the series except the one which is in `a`

So, the final output should look like this

```
Clusters
Cluster 1    1
Cluster 4    1
Cluster 5    8
```

for subtraction every element I can simply do

```
(cluster_grtr_6 - 6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask. First find the index labels in `a`

```
In [64]: s.index.isin(a)
Out[64]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Then use the fact that True is treated as 1 and False as 0 in numeric operations

```
In [65]: result = s - 6 * ~s.index.isin(a)

In [66]: result
Out[66]:
cluster 1    1
cluster 4    1
cluster 5    8
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use following (if you have only one value in `a`):

```
s = pd.Series([7,7,8], index=['Cluster 1', 'Cluster 4', 'Cluster 5'])
a = pd.Series(['Cluster 5'], index = [3])

In [42]: 6*(s.index != a.iloc[0])
Out[42]: array([6, 6, 0])

In [43]: s - 6*(s.index != a.iloc[0])
Out[43]:
Cluster 1    1
Cluster 4    1
Cluster 5    8
dtype: int64

In [44]: %timeit s - 6 * ~s.index.isin(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 us per loop

In [45]: %timeit s - 6*(s.index != a.iloc[0])
10000 loops, best of 3: 144 us per loop
```

It's a little bit faster but could be used only with one variable in `a`